# How to repair rotting porch pt plate & cedar posts?

Tags: repair, wood, water-damage, timber-framing

Any suggestions on how best to repair the massive rot all around our screen porch as shown in the attached photos, without having to completely open up the area above the posts in which the tops our contained by about a foot of very expensive clear cedar siding we relly don't want to damage? We are thinking of cutting the posts about a foot from the bottom (a couple at a time while jacking up that area with 2x6s; putting some kind of moisture barrier/flashing under the new pt plate, putting approx 12" of new 4x4 post in area that has been cut out due to rot, then sistering 2x4 cedar studs on either side of the repaired posts, wrapping the front and back of posts with 1x cedar to hide the cut marks.[image: porch damage]

Comment: Is that a concrete stem wall below the rot?

Comment: @Huesmann it is. There is pink sill sealer between the wall and pt plate, but it still rotted, and we can't figure out how to repair so that it doesn't just rot again. We are in a very moist area with lots of rain. Appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you find the point where the posts are not rotten, and rig temporary supports to hold them up while you cut the bottoms off and replace the rotten stuff below.

There are multiple ways to accomplish that, and which works best is going to be specific to the sort of access you have to rig supports you can work around. It's not uncommon to support them all so that the work below can be done in one step, but if doing a few at a time is more comfortable for you, you can do that. Ideally you time the project to be done before snow comes, if snow load is applicable in your area.

Examples include individual timbers or pairs supporting each post, and running a long beam across to support all of them from beyond the foundation. If you can set them in a way that you can work around them, Lally columns with built-in jacking screws can be handy.

Comment: thank you for your reply. We are trying to figure out the best way to secure the new post bottoms to the concrete wall/a new PT plate so that this doesn't just happen again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a better grade of PT (such as "ground contact rated") than you did the first time, and look at water management (where it goes when it comes off the porch deck) as well. Post base hardware is pretty widely available in many types, for the attachment of the post to the plate. But the main aspects of not repeating this are materials that are more rot resistant, and limiting the water exposure as much as practical.

Comment: Also (as you can see in the pic, the plate doesn't need to be continuous.  You can replace parts are you are able to support the roof, i.e. replace Plate A while you support Roof A and replace Plate B while you support Roof B.